# Executing complicated MySQL query efficiently

Tags: mysql, sql, database

### Problem

Given a user query `Q` on a webpage, I am attempting to compute the following somewhat complex function for each entity `p` in my database:

[image]

(`D` is also dependent upon the user query `Q`) There are roughly 440,000 `p` entities in my database, and each has an average of ~50 associated `w_{d,p}` weights and ~400 associated `u_{p, c}` weights. Right now, these weights are stored across three tables, and there is an additional table that defines the relationship between `d` and `c`:

```
table              columns                indices
-----              -------                ----
w weights:         p | d | w_pd           primary key (p, d), index on d
u weights:         p | c | u_pc           primary key (p, c), index on c
v weights:         c | v_c                primary key c
d/c relationship:  d | c                  primary key (d, c), index on c
```

The IDs `p`, `d` and `c` are all varchars ranging in size from 10-16. `w_dp`, `u_pc`, and `v_c` are floats.

My current approach to computing the above equation involves multiple joins, subqueries, group by statements, etc. Depending on the `Q`, we may be able to trim the set of `p` entities we are interested in down to a more manageable number, and the computation may only take a few seconds. But some values of `Q` result in a computation that takes multiple minutes.

### Example computation

Suppose we have the following four tables:

```
d/c relationship   w weights           u weights        v weights
d  | c             p  | d  | w_dp      p  | c  | u_pc   c  | v_c 
d1 | c1            p1 | d1 | 1         p1 | c1 | 6      c1 | 12
d1 | c2            p1 | d2 | 3         p1 | c2 | 8      c2 | 16
d2 | c2            p2 | d1 | 2         p2 | c1 | 11     c3 | 15
d3 | c3            p3 | d2 | 4         p3 | c2 | 7
                   p3 | d3 | 5         p3 | c3 | 9
                   p4 | d3 | 10        p4 | c1 | 13
```

The query `Q` is actually a set of `c` IDs, that restricts the set `D` that the sum is over. So let's say `Q = {c1, c2}`. Using the d/c relationship table, our sum is then over `d1` and `d2`. Computing the sum for `p1`, we have:

```
d1: 1 * max(6, 8) * [v_c : c = argmax_c (u_11=6, u_12=8)] = 1 * 8 * 16 = 128
d2: 3 * max(8) * [v_c : c = argmax_c (u_12=8)] = 3 * 8 * 16 = 384
```

So the score for `p1` is 128 + 384 = 512. We would do a similar computation for `p2` and `p3`. `p4` is only associated with `d3`, and `d3` has no relation with `Q = {c1, c2}`, so we have nothing to sum for `p4`.

### Question

Is there any sensible way to compute the above function quickly? In particular,

1. Using the existing db schema? My understanding is that using aggregate functions over joined tables like I am currently doing is quite slow, so I'm guessing the answer to this question is "no".
2. Using an alternative table structure? My only current idea is to join the w/u/v weights into one massive, ~700m row table, and use that table for the query. I'm not sure how helpful this will be, but maybe if properly indexed could be faster.
3. Should I do something else entirely? Is there an alternative data storage/processing tool I should be considering?

Because I am very much a novice when it comes to SQL, I was hoping to get a clearer sense of direction before I waste too much time on a dead end.

### Update

I know this didn't get much traction, but for future viewers: the way I solved this was by doing all computations ahead of time. There are about 5000 possible queries `q`, and a maximum of ~500,000 entities `p`. This would result in a table of size 2.5 billion rows, where `(p, q)` is the primary key. In reality, for each query q, only roughly 75k entities are assigned scores, on average, resulting in a slightly more manageable table size of 75000*5000 = 375,000,000. Now at query time, all I need to do to get the relevant list of scores is filter on `q`, which is much simpler than doing this crazy summation.

That said, if anyone sees this and has input, I'd still like to hear the opinion of any SQL/MySQL experts out there.

Comment: You have written your question using pure mathematical notation.  While there is nothing wrong with this per se, most people who will be reading your question will expect to see database notation instead.  Can you add a sample of your input data table and then show us the expected output?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @TimBiegeleisen. I added an "example computation" section with four example input tables, and a (partial) computation of the above function. I'm not totally sure this resolves your comment, but please let me know if I should add more.

Comment: Max -> `max()` ,  argmax_c -> `max() GROUP BY c having...` or `row_number() OVER ()`, which is probably more elegant here.

Comment: It would help if you put the DDL + data into some usable form. (it would cost me ~30 minutes, which I am not willing to spend)