# Efficiently computing large summation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Earlier, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58586218/executing-complicated-mysql-query-efficiently) about computing a somewhat complicated function in MySQL. I have another related question that's a bit more straightforward, and may help with the previous question. I want to compute the following function at query time:

[image]

My tables are as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `w_weights` (
   p VarChar(20) NOT NULL, 
   q VarChar(10) NOT NULL, 
   w_weight Float NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (p, q),
   INDEX q
);

CREATE TABLE `v_weights` (
    t VarChar(10) NOT NULL, 
    p VarChar(20) NOT NULL,
    v_weight Float NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (t, p), 
    INDEX p
);

CREATE TABLE `t_q_map` (
   t VarChar(10) NOT NULL,
   q VarChar(10) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (t, q),
   INDEX q
)
```

The computation is done relative to `p` -- there are about 400,000 `p`s in our database, and we need to do the sum above for each `p`. The one other detail is that the summation is over `t` in `q'`, not `q`. `q'` is basically an expanded set of identifiers formed from the initial `q` (this expansion is done independently of the database query). For the sake of the following example, let `q = 'q0'`, and `q' = ('q0', 'q1', 'q2', 'q3')`. This is the query I currently use:

```sql
SELECT vw.p, ww.w_weight * SUM(vw.v_weight) AS score
FROM (
    SELECT p, v_weight 
    FROM v_weights 
    WHERE t IN (SELECT t FROM t_q_map WHERE q IN ('q0', 'q1', 'q2', 'q3'))
) vw
JOIN w_weights AS ww ON (vw.p = ww.p AND ww.q = 'q0')
GROUP BY vw.p
ORDER BY score DESC
```

The tables<sup>1</sup> are large (both `weight` tables are on the order of 10's of millions of rows, while the `t_q_map` table is a few hundred thousand rows), so depending on the query `q`, the computation can take quite a while. I don't think there's any `q` which will result in scores for all 400,000 `p`'s, but some `q's` do result in ~100,000-200,000 `p's` getting assigned scores, which means we have to return all of those rows.

My current solution is to precompute all scores for every `q` (there are roughly 5000 possible `q`'s, and that set will not change often), and store those scores in a table, but this is quite unwieldy -- if any of the underlying weight tables change, then I have to reconstruct that large table again. I'm hoping there's some dynamic approach here that's smarter than my naive query above. I'm also open to more involved solutions, e.g., moving away from mysql if there is another RDBMS or tool that is better suited to computations like this, etc.

---

1: As a side note, the tables for the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58586218/executing-complicated-mysql-query-efficiently) share nearly the same structure, but that query is complicated by the inclusion of an `argmax` inside the summation

Comment: Sample data and desired results -- in a text table format -- are much, much, much more useful than a mathematic formula that refers to symbols that are obviously not column names.

Comment: A Query plan would help

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT vw.p, ww.w_weight * SUM(vw.v_weight) AS score
FROM v_weights vw
JOIN t _q_map qmap on qmap.t = vw.t 
JOIN w_weights AS ww ON (vw.p = ww.p AND ww.q = 'q0')
Where qmap.q in ('q0', 'q1', 'q2', 'q3')
GROUP BY vw.p
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Sub selects in mysql are slow. It's unlikely to be the levels of maths here which is causing the slow down. More likely to be the getting the data together to do the maths.

Alternatively as you say the data doesn't change much. You can make a temporary table or even a full table with the result of the sub query and join on it direct.